# Only display the day with the max profit per store

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sum, max

Only display the day with the max profit per store in SQL Server

For example only {Monday 5929.00 DARIEN BRONX GOODS} should only show for DARIEN BRONX GOODS

What I have so far.

```
select
    Dim_Date.WeekDayName,
    sum(dbo.DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_PRICE) as [Total Profit],
    DIM_D_STORE.STORE_NAME as [Store Name]
from
    dbo.DIM_EMPLOYEE
inner join dbo.S_ORDER_FACT on
    dbo.DIM_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_EMPLOYEEID
inner join dbo.DIM_CUSTOMER on
    dbo.DIM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_CUSTOMERID
inner join dbo.Dim_Date on
    dbo.Dim_Date.DateKey = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_DATEID
inner join dbo.DIM_D_STORE on
    dbo.DIM_D_STORE.STOREID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_STOREID
inner join dbo.DIM_PRODUCT on
    dbo.DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_PRODUCTID
group by
    DIM_D_STORE.STORE_NAME,
    Dim_Date.WeekDayName
order by
    DIM_D_STORE.STORE_NAME,
    [Total Profit] desc 
offset 0 rows ;
```

[Output in image ]

[image: 1]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And we need sample data to match the expected results ideally as DDL+DML.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode is relevant to Dale K's comment.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way using window functions:

```
select * from ( 
select
    Dim_Date.WeekDayName,
    sum(dbo.DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_PRICE) as [Total Profit],
    DIM_D_STORE.STORE_NAME as [Store Name],
    rank() over (partition by STORE_NAME order by sum(dbo.DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_PRICE) desc) rn 
from
    dbo.DIM_EMPLOYEE
inner join dbo.S_ORDER_FACT on
    dbo.DIM_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_EMPLOYEEID
inner join dbo.DIM_CUSTOMER on
    dbo.DIM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_CUSTOMERID
inner join dbo.Dim_Date on
    dbo.Dim_Date.DateKey = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_DATEID
inner join dbo.DIM_D_STORE on
    dbo.DIM_D_STORE.STOREID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_STOREID
inner join dbo.DIM_PRODUCT on
    dbo.DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_PRODUCTID
group by
    DIM_D_STORE.STORE_NAME,
    Dim_Date.WeekDayName 
) table where rn = 1
```

Comment: you are welcome , please accept / upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `Top 1` do the job for selecting highest profit?

```
select Top 1,
    Dim_Date.WeekDayName,
    sum(dbo.DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_PRICE) as [Total Profit],
    DIM_D_STORE.STORE_NAME as [Store Name]
from
    dbo.DIM_EMPLOYEE
inner join dbo.S_ORDER_FACT on
    dbo.DIM_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_EMPLOYEEID
inner join dbo.DIM_CUSTOMER on
    dbo.DIM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_CUSTOMERID
inner join dbo.Dim_Date on
    dbo.Dim_Date.DateKey = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_DATEID
inner join dbo.DIM_D_STORE on
    dbo.DIM_D_STORE.STOREID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_STOREID
inner join dbo.DIM_PRODUCT on
    dbo.DIM_PRODUCT.PRODUCTID = dbo.S_ORDER_FACT.ORDER_PRODUCTID
group by
    DIM_D_STORE.STORE_NAME,
    Dim_Date.WeekDayName
order by
    [Total Profit] desc,
    DIM_D_STORE.STORE_NAME
```